# Cannot set property 'className' of null on form verification js script

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, verification

I am trying to make the border of a textbox red when a text that does not containthe "@" is typed in (it is an email checker). Unfortunately, this does not happen.

I have tried to use a class that contains the new border color but unfortunately, it seems that this change is never applied.

This is the html and js code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>
    Sign Up Page
</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="screen"/>
</head>

<body>

<script>
    function validateForm() {

            var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
            if (x == "") {
            alert("something must be filled out");
            return false;
            }
            else if (!(x.includes("@"))) 
           {
             alert("you must have to filled value with @");

 document.getElementById("nameT").style.color="red";

 document.getElementById("fname").className = 'error';
             return false;
           }
          }
 </script>

 <div class="ocean">
       <div class="wave"></div>
       <div class="wave"></div>
       </div>
       <h1>
          <center>
             Whale
          </center>
       </h1>
       <div class="loginbox">

         <h2>
           Login
         </h2>
         <form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" 
         method="post">
             <p id="nameT"> email </p>
             <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="enter 
   email" onblur="validateForm()">
              <p name="passT"> password </p>
              <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="enter 
   password">
              <br>
              <input type="submit" value="Submit">
              <br>
              <a href="#"> 
                 Lost your password? 
              </a>
              <br>
              <a href="#"> 
                 Create an account 
              </a>
          </form>
        </div>
    </body>

  </html>
```

This is the css code:

```
 html, body { height: 100%; }
 body {
   background:radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(255,254,234,1) 
 0%, rgba(255,254,234,1) 35%, #ffffff 100%);
  overflow: hidden;
 }

.ocean { 
  height: 5%;
 width:100%;
 position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
 left:0;
 background: #ffffff;
 }

 .wave {
  background: url(https://s3-us-west- 
  2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/85486/wave.svg) repeat-x; 
  position: absolute;
  top: -198px;
  width: 6400px;
  height: 198px;
  animation: wave 7s cubic-bezier( 0.36, 0.45, 0.63, 0.53) 
 infinite;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }

.wave:nth-of-type(2) {
 top: -175px;
  animation: wave 7s cubic-bezier( 0.36, 0.45, 0.63, 0.53) -.125s 
  infinite, swell 7s ease -1.25s infinite;
  opacity: 1;
  }

  @keyframes wave {
  0% {
   margin-left: 0;
   }
   100% {
    margin-left: -1600px;
    }
    }

  @keyframes swell {
   0%, 100% {
   transform: translate3d(0,-25px,0);
   }
   50% {
    transform: translate3d(0,5px,0);
   }
  }

  .loginbox
 {
  width: 340px;
  height: 360px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  top: 50%;
  left:50%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }
 h2
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px; 
}



 .loginbox input
{
 width: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.loginbox input[type="text"], input[type="password"]
{
 border: none;

 border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
 background: transparent;
 outline: none;
 height: 40px;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 16px;
 }

 .loginbox input[type="submit"]
 {
 border: none;
 outline: none;
 height: 48px;
 background: #fb2525;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 18px;
 border-radius: 20px;
 } 

 .loginbox input[type="submit"]:hover
 {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #ffc107;
  color: #000;
 }

 .loginbox a
 {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: darkgrey;
 }

 .loginbox p
 {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 10px;
   font-weight: bold;
  }
  .loginbox a:hover
  {
    color: #ffc107;
  }
    .error{
     border:2px solid red;
     }
```

The expected output is the border becoming red if the "@" symbol is not typed into the email textbox. The actual result is no such effect and instead, a "cannot set property 'className' of null" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `document.getElementById("fname")` but you do not have any `id` which has name `"fname"` so update input as,

```
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="enter 
   email" onblur="validateForm()">
```

Change the `getElementById` to,

```
document.getElementById("fname").classList.add('error');
```

and change your `.error` class to,

```
.error{
    border-bottom:2px solid red !important;
}
```

Comment: I have updated the answer now it is working fine you can check it.

Comment: You are the best. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try it by accessing elements via `document.forms` as below

```js
function validateForm() {

  var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
  if (x == "") {
    alert("something must be filled out");
    return false;
  } else if (!(x.includes("@"))) {
    alert("you must have to filled value with @");
    document.forms.myForm.name.style.color = "red";
    document.forms.myForm.name.style.border = "1px solid red";
    document.forms.myForm.fname.className = 'error';
    return false;
  } else {
    document.forms.myForm.name.style.color = "#000";
    document.forms.myForm.name.style.border = "1px solid #000";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="ocean">
  <div class="wave"></div>
  <div class="wave"></div>
</div>
<h1>
  <center>
    Whale
  </center>
</h1>
<div class="loginbox">

  <h2>
    Login
  </h2>
  <form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
    <p id="nameT"> email </p>
    <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="enter 
   email" onblur="validateForm()">
    <p name="passT"> password </p>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="enter 
   password">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    <br>
    <a href="#"> 
                 Lost your password? 
              </a>
    <br>
    <a href="#"> 
                 Create an account 
              </a>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this as well and it does not seem to work unfortunately.

Comment: it shows an alert and also makes the `password` red, isn't that you were trying to achieve?

Comment: Those effects I already have. The additional effect I want is for the line bellow the text box to also turn from white into red.

Comment: @WargameElliot I have updated the code. I believe the line which you are referring to is the `border`.

Answer (score 0):

just add `id=fname` in your text field and replace your js with my js

```
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="enter email" 
 onblur="validateForm()">
```

Here is js

```
function validateForm() {
            document.getElementById("nameT").style.color = "white";
            var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
            if (x == "") {
            alert("something must be filled out");
            return false;
            } else if (!(x.includes("@"))) {
alert("you must have to filled value with @");
         document.getElementById("nameT").style.color = "red";
         document.getElementById("fname").className = 'error';
         return false;
}
}
```

[here is demo on jsbin](https://jsbin.com/waricatolu/edit?html,css,js,output)